# Does ELMAH have flood protection implemented and enabled by default?

Tags: asp.net, logging, elmah, error-logging

Can anyone confirm that Elmah implements flood protection behavior and that this behavior is enabled by default, or is easily enabled via web.config? If so, is the time threshold configurable?

I proposed setting up the Elmah database schema to our database, but our DBA has legitimate concerns about error logs consuming significant storage space if an error occurs across the board for our hundreds of thousands or millions of web visitors. I thought I had seen behavior in Elmah to filter out duplicate exception logs if a certain time threshold had not been met, but I have not been able to validate this behavior doing a Google search for documentation on this feature.

Comment: We have definitely found that the ELMAH errors consume a lot of space in the database.  Our SQL Server database was rapidly growing and we found that ELMAH was the culprit.  Our problem was that ELMAH catches request validation errors from malicious users.  We filtered out those errors and it slowed the growth.

Comment: I'm using ELMAH in Azure and, unless I am missing something, I am not seeing it filter duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have not seen it, Scott Mitchell's article "Keeping ELMAH's Error Log Size In Check" touches on this subject, and may help.

http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/07/10/163355.aspx